# Alternative for swi prologs clpq library for soving simplex

Tags: optimization, prolog, constraint-programming, clpq

Excuse me if this is the wrong place to ask.

I have been using SWI Prolog's clpq library to solve simplex. I find the syntax pretty simple and expressive. It looks like this:

```
:- use_module(library(clpq)).

main(U, V, W) :-
        { 0 =< U, U =< 1,
          0 =< V, V =< 1,
          0 =< W, W =< 1
        },
        maximize(U + V - W).
```

No need to convert into any special format, you just type your constraints and the object function. Great, but it has come to my attention that clpq has bugs and is un-maintained, so I lack confidence in it.

So I was wondering if someone knows something opensource and equally as simple, without bugs? The best I have found so far is the GNU linear programming kit. What are other people using for experimenting with simplex?

Comment: The clpq-library in SWI stems from the original library in SICStus. It is very widely used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the archive, the simplex implementation in maxima (http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) is very good.